# can not find module while mocking a libarary in JEST?

Tags: testing, jestjs, svelte

I am using a module name as `prop-types` https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types.
In .svelte file using:

```
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    const { checkPropTypes, bool, func, string } = PropTypes;
```

I am trying to mock this like:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
jest.mock("PropTypes", () => jest.fn());
PropTypes.mockImplementation(() => ({ checkPropTypes, bool, func, string }));
```

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op7MF.png)

Cannot find module 'PropTypes' from 'src/components/....

```
   6 | const loading = false;
   7 | import PropTypes from "prop-types";
>  8 | jest.mock("PropTypes", () => jest.fn());
```

Comment: Why do you want to _mock_ prop-types?

Comment: Facing this issue `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'checkPropTypes' of 'PropTypes' as it is undefined.`

Comment: @jonrsharpe while testing the code.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If you _didn't_ mock it all of its properties would be available.

Comment: don't now Why I am not able to destructure

Comment: @jonrsharpe If I think independently then why module is not find.